# Python Pandas Dataframe with lists elements reports wrong type when calling `.info()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in Python 3 that looks like

```
>>> df_people
       name Information 1 Information 2
0      P1   [20, 21]      [50, 52]
1      P2   [30, 20]      [52, 55]
2      P3   [25, 33]      [60, 54]
```

created from the following code:

```
people = {"name":["P1", "P2", "P3"],"Information 1":[[20, 21],[30, 20],[25,33]],"Information 2":[[50, 52],[52, 55],[60,54]]}
df_people= pd.DataFrame(people)
df_people
```

Now, if I call `df_people.info()` I get:

```
>>> df_people.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
name             3 non-null object
Information 1    3 non-null object
Information 2    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
```

The `non-null object` part worries me. Should it report something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You should not worry about the `non-null objects`.

This method shows you the information about a DataFrame including the ***index dtype*** and ***column dtypes***, ***non-null values*** and ***memory usage***.

It is just showing you that the data you fill inside it are not null i.e `not blank`.

You can also visit the official documentation of pandas dataframe about `.info()` here :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html

Comment: Thanks very much! As an aside, if I wanted to report them as lists, is there an option in `.info()` for that? I've gone through the reference and don't see anything for that.

Comment: I didn't get you... What do you mean about report them as list? Is it viewing the info in a list or something else?

Comment: I am hoping for `.info()` to report that the elements under "Information 1" and "Information 2" are "lists" objects. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Nope. I read the documentation, searched the internet and try it in my editor but i can't find any possibilities of showing, if the data is a list or not. To do that, maybe you have to import an another library for this...

Comment: @user321627 Just wanted to budge in to confirm that object is the appropriate dtype. Pandas supports NumPy dtypes plus a few of its own. You could write your own [extension type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-extension-types ), but it sounds like a lot of work ;) If your lists are always the same length, however, you could just make them into columns. Can you share some more context for this program? How did you end up with lists in a DataFrame?